# How to install portia, a python application from Github (Mac)

Tags: python, git, github, web-scraping, scrapy

I am attempting to install Portia, a python app from Github: https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia

I use the following steps at the command line:

1. set up new virtualenv 'portia' in Mac terminal
2. git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia.git
3. follow readme instructions:

   `cd slyd`

   `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. run Portia

   `cd slyd`

   `twistd -n slyd`

But every time I attempt the last step to run the program, I get the following error:

`ImportError: No module named scrapy`

Any idea why this error is occurring? All previous steps seem to install correctly. Is it an error earlier in my install process?

Thanks!

Comment: Did `pip install -r requirements.txt` work correctly? `scrapy` is listed there so should have installed. Does `python -c "import scrapy"` show any errors?

Comment: Yes, `pip install -r requirements.txt` installed correctly. 
Yes, `python -c "import scrapy"` showed the error: `ImportError: No module named scrapy`

Comment: What does `pip list` show?  (Make sure to run it with your virtualenv activated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have the rep to upvote Alagappan's answer but he's correct. Also, if you're as inexperienced as I am, you may need further clarity on this.

You have to create, activate and ***navigate into*** the virtualenv before installing anything (including cloning portia from github). Here's the whole thing working from start to finish:

**1: cd** *to wherever you’d like to store your project...
and* **Install virtualenv**:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

**2: Create the virtual environment.** *(I called mine “portia” but this can be anything.)*:

```
$ virtualenv portia
```

**3: Activate the virtual environment you created** *(change the path to reflect the name you used here if not “portia”.)*:

```
$ source portia/bin/activate
```

*At this point your terminal should have display the virtualenv name in parenthesis before the standard directory path prompt:*  `(name-of-virtualenv) [your-machine]:[current-directory]: [user]$`
*...and if you list the files within your pwd you’ll see the name of you virtualenv there.*

**4: cd into your virtualenv (“portia” for me):**

```
$ cd portia
```

**5: Now you can clone portia from github into your virtualenv...**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia
```

**6: cd into the cloned portia/slyd...**

```
$ cd portia/slyd
```

**7/8: pip install twisted and Scrapy...**

```
$ pip install twisted
$ pip install Scrapy
```

*You’re virtualenv should still be activated and you should still be in [virtualenv-name]/portia/slyd*

**9: Install the requirements.txt:**

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**10: Run slyd:**

```
$ twistd -n slyd
```

*--- No more scrapy error! ---*

Comment: This is older than current instructions under [portia's readme](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia/blob/master/README.md) and it just works! You should update that readme yourself. ;-)

Comment: (down4keeps, I suggest you add this to your answer!) If you need to run it again, after having "installed" it with the steps above, try to create this simple shell script:
    `#!/bin/bash`
    `cd [your folder]`
    `virtualenv portia`
    `source portia/bin/activate`
    `cd portia/portia/slyd`
    `twistd -n slyd`

Answer (score 1):

### Another Installation Method For Portia: Using Vagrant

Here is the method that made me install Portia with ease. Works with Mac, Windows and Linux. With a few commands and clicks, you'll get a fully functional web scraper.

#### Things Needed:

1. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
2. [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)
3. Clone the repo for [`Portia`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia) or download the zip file.

#### Additional Steps To Take:

1. Install `VirtualBox`.
2. Install `Vagrant`
3. Open your terminal and navigate to where you cloned the `Portia` repo or where you've extracted it (in case of a zip file).
4. Then make a command `vagrant up` - This will download and setup a VirtualBox Guest VM for you + will install all the necessary requirements for Portia and will install Portia from start to finished.

After the above process, you may now open your browser and navigate to

```
http://the-virtualbox-ip:8000/static/main.html
```

And you're setup.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, you just need to install the python module `scrapy` in the same way that the Twitter API requires `setuptools`

```
pip install scrapy
```

Comment: thanks - I tried that too. still getting error `No module named scrapy` even after making sure it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the issue you are facing is because of the virtualenv. Once you setup a new virtual environment you need to run the activate script in order to start using it. In your case you'll have to run the following command:

```
$ source portia/bin/activate
```

On successful activation, your prompt will look like:

```
(portia) $
```

Can you check if you activated your virtual environment before you installed the packages using pip? I believe doing so will fix your issue.