# Unable to install portia due to IO Error

Tags: web, web-scraping, portia

I am trying to install portia using the following link. But unable to run slyd. Its throwing IO Error. Kindly help.

[How to install portia, a python application from Github (Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453054/how-to-install-portia-a-python-application-from-github-mac)

The error trace is the following,

```
(portia) nn@nn-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:~/Documents/portia/portia/slyd$ twistd -n slyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/bin/twistd", line 14, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 29, in run
    app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 617, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 25, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 348, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 408, in createOrGetApplication
    ser = plg.makeService(self.config.subOptions)
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/portia/slyd/slyd/tap.py", line 107, in makeService
    root = create_root(config, settings_module)
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/portia/slyd/slyd/tap.py", line 45, in create_root
    from .projectspec import create_project_resource
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/portia/slyd/slyd/projectspec.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .utils.projects import allowed_file_name, ProjectModifier
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/portia/slyd/slyd/utils/projects.py", line 6, in <module>
    from slybot.validation.schema import get_schema_validator
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slybot/validation/schema.py", line 23, in <module>
    _SCHEMAS = load_schemas()
  File "/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slybot/validation/schema.py", line 21, in load_schemas
    return dict((s["id"], s) for s in json.load(open(filename)))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/nn/Documents/portia/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slybot/validation/schemas.json'
(portia) nn@nn-HP-Pavilion-14-Notebook-PC:~/Documents/portia/portia/slyd$
```

Comment: can someone please help me in the above problem

Comment: Which version of Portia you are using? It seems you are not using latest version.